# Where is Wade from s6e6 of walking dead in season 8?

Tags: character, the-walking-dead

Where is Wade from The Walking Dead, s6e6? What is the not-in-universe reason the character has not been in the show since (eg. did the show wrote itself into a corner or change of character direction, etc.)?

In s6e6 of TWD, Daryl meets some of the first Saviors seen on the show (Dwight, Sherry, and Tina) as they are on the run from other Saviors led by someone called Wade, whose face in never shown. The show is currently on s8e5 and the character Wade has not been seen again (even during the meeting of the Savior captains before the horde attack on the Savior compound).

Was this supposed to be some kind of initial misdirection for introducing the character of Negan? Is Wade a character from the comics they were just homage-ing to? The episode where he appeared seemed to give time to introducing him with a specific kind of personality (rather than some generic bad guy), so it seems weird that we have not seen that character ever since and not know what happened with him.

Comment: No evidence to support it, but I'm thinking Wade was slaughtered in his sleep when Rick's gang raided that radio building (which they thought, at the time, was the whole Saviours, but it turned out to only be the *closest outpost* to where Rick's group was at the time.)

Comment: @Steve-O (I know you prefaced with acknowledging no supporting evidence, but for sake of information if anyone else sees this post...) The large truck that Wade uses to hunt down Dwight et al. through the forest in s6e6 was not among the vehicles that Rick et al. capture at the end of the episode. Also, there is no show of the s6e6 guy who got is arm amputated to stop the infection (I would think that the show would have put them in there if these were indeed the same people and they were trying to be consistent, something short just to be like 'hey remember these guys?').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems Wade was killed in the "All Out War" between Rick's combined forces and Negan's Saviors. The only thing I could find on this subject is in TWD Wiki and it reads: "In the many skirmishes against the Saviors throughout the Washington D.C. area, including the various battles during the All Out War, hundreds of Saviors have been killed. While Wade has not been seen since the incident in the woods, it is likely he is among the many Saviors killed during the war. Additionally, Wade has not been seen among the reformed Saviors after the war or as a member of one of the communities after the six year time skip. However, his ultimate fate remains unknown"

It also suggest Wade was killed during the All Out War by one of Eugene's bullet malfunctions.

This is a great question. And the ultimate answer seems to be either he is already dead and we will never know, or have yet to find out.